# Consulta data e hora para identificar turno

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela de parametro de turnos com hora de inicio e fim. Preciso executar uma consulta pra identificar se a hora esta dentro de qual turno.

Dados da Tabela

Turno | inicio | fim

T1 | 08:00 | 18:00

T2 | 22:00 | 05:00

CONSULTA

SELECT * FROM turno WHERE '2023-01-01 01:00' BETWEEN inicio AND fim

O que acontece é que a data e hora consultada iniciou às 1:00 da manha e assim deveria reconhecer que esta dentro do turno T2

Comment: Qual o tipo das colunas inicio e fim? Se for `TIME`, poderia extrair somente o horário da data e comparar com elas. O problema é que no T2 o horário fim é "menor" (pq na verdade se refere ao dia seguinte), então teria que ser algo assim: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d09a8a/3

Comment: @hkotsubo deu certo parcialmente. Quando a hora for exatamente a mesma do inicio nao reconhece, por exemplo 22:00 nao reconhece que esta no turno 2

Comment: Ué, é só trocar `>` por `>=` no inicio (e claro, `<=` no fim)

Comment: Acho que agora deu certo, vou fazer simulaçoes, mas de qualquer forma ajudou demais, valeu!!!!